# How to set loaders in products image based on image loading in magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

Is it possible to **set Image loaders for all products** while delaying to load images in **magento 2.2.5**

Comment: Do you mean lazy load on product listing page?

Comment: its by default feature in magento 2, check your theme for more 
http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/hero-hoodie.html

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala I want to set spinners for products listing page not product details page -> is there any option

Comment: @LAW - No lazy load, a list of products needs spinner for individual item's image